# How should I template my site in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, templates, jsp, struts, tile

I'm using Eclipse for the first time, wondering which way to go about templating it?  I know a little about tiles and jsp's, zero about databases.

the site:

- static header, nav, sidebar, and footer
- a few different content jsp's
- main question is --> I have one content section with one layout but 100's of varying jsp's...how should I go about this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Struts and databases are related to this, but basically, `<jsp:include>` is the best what you can get in JSP.

Basic kickoff example of `/WEB-INF/template.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            header
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            menu
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/${view}.jsp" />
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the controller [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info):

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/pages/*"})
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String view = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        String title = titles.get(view); // Imagine that it's a map or something.

        request.setAttribute("view", view);
        request.setAttribute("title", title);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/template.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Invoke it by

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/pages/foo

and provide a `/WEB-INF/foo.jsp` file which should represent the content. E.g.

`/WEB-INF/foo.jsp`

```
<h1>This is Foo!</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```